# how CPU distributes data from network?

Tags: tcp, operating-system, nic

I'm learning network communications and already familiar with TCP/IP networking layers (physical, data link ... and application layers) and how data moves through this nodes. But I have some questions about what happens inside a machine, when data is received by a Network Interface Card(NIC).

Questions:

1. How CPU knows that data from other machine is arrived?
2. How CPU informs OS that data from other machine is arrived?
3. How OS knows which application the data is for?

Please, give me some deep explanation for this topic, or advice some useful materials to make it clear.

Comment: Google 'interrupts', 'drivers'.  You already know the answer to (3).

Answer (score 4):

To give you a general view from Linux point(should be similar for other OS):

The packets arrive in NIC. These packets are copied into circular queues in RAM via DMA. The arrival of packets will generate an interrupt to let the system know that their are packets in RAM. Corresponding to the interrupt there will be an interrupt handler routine registered with the Operating System via the network driver.  (To keep things simple didn't talk about softirq's). Each CPU has a poll function whose job is to harvest packets from these queue's and pass them onto upper n/w layers. So answering your queries:

**How CPU knows that data from other machine is arrived?**
When interrupt occurs and poll loop is not running on the CPU, the OS(via network driver)
will ask the CPU to start the poll loop for harvesting the packets.

**How CPU informs OS that data from other machine is arrived?**
CPU doesn't need to inform OS. The OS will know when the interrupt occurs as the interrupt handler is a part of the network driver which is part of OS. Infact in a way OS will tell the CPU to start harvesting packets.

**How OS knows which application the data is for?**
The communication is done via sockets which will have a port number. The packets arrived will have a port number which will guide the OS to take the packet to the required application.